# Why are breakpoints invisible in Matlab Editor windows?

Tags: debugging, matlab

I have been having the following curious issue with Matlab's debug mode recently. I typically use the debugger heavily -- usually by setting breakpoints on individual lines in the Editor window, resulting in the normal red-circle image denoting a line with a breakpoint on it.

For the past few days, I have been unable to get these breakpoints to visible show up. I click a line and the red circle partially shows up (as I am holding the mouse click) and then disappears. Note that the breakpoint is active, as checked by either dbstatus or by simply running the code. When execution breaks at the appropriate line and the program pauses, I have no visual confirmation that it is paused at that line (i.e. the typical arrow pointer in the Editor window) except for the status message saying I am in debug mode. One interesting twist is that I can see the breakpoints if I have unsaved changes to the code, but they disappear once I save (as is normal) and I cannot see them as long as the file has no unsaved changes.

There are no uses of clear or clear all in the code, but I want to re-emphasize that the breakpoints are not inactive, they are simply not visible. The error is reproducible using the simplest one-line function.

Comment: I have had this problem occur periodically.  I find that I have to restart matlab to restore sanity.  Saving and reloading the workspace makes this fairly painless.

Comment: I suggest you submit a bug report for that [here](http://www.mathworks.com/support/). Note that you may have to create a (free) account.

Answer (score 2):

I have experienced the same bug, I can't remember on which MATLAB version but is was only present using the 64 bit version and not the x86 bit version. The newest versions of MATLAB 64 bit does not have the same problem.

Another way for this to happen is if you have some relative paths on your path in MATLAB, instead of e.g

```
addpath('C:\topdir\subdir1\..\subdir2');
```

do

```
addpath('C:\topdir\subdir2');
```

[See this helpfull post on the subject](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/163984)

Answer (score -2):

I had the same issue.

I copy the content of the function where the breakpoints did not show up and past it to a new function.

Delete the old function and paste the new one with the same name in the same directory.

This solves the issue.  My breakpoints are now visible as before.